# Cuda Source to Source translation using Rose compiler

Tags: compilation, cuda, rose-compiler-framework

I would like to know about the extent of support for cuda in rose compiler. I am trying to build a source to source translator for cuda. Is it possible using Rose compiler? Which distribution of Rose compiler should I use?

I know this has been discussed earlier (support for cuda in rose compiler), but I cannot understand whether cuda support is there or not. Rose user manual does not have much information either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rose has a C++ front end and a Fortran front end that seem reasonably well integrated.  The Rose system design IMHO is not amenable to easy integration of other front end parsers (such as you would need presumably to parse Cuda), although with enough effort you could do it. (Rose originally only had C++, and Fortran was grafted on).
If you don't see explicit mention of Cuda in the Rose manuals, its pretty like because it simply isn't there.

If you want to process Cuda using source to source transformations, you'll need both a Cuda parser and an appropriate set of transformation machinery something like what Rose has.

I cannot offer you a Cuda parser, but my company does provide industrial strength source-to-source program transformation systems in the form the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).

DMS has been used to carry out massive transformations on large C++ systems, so I think it quite reasonable to say it is at least as competent as Rose for that purpose.  DMS has also been used to process extremely large C and Fortran systems, and other codes in Java, C#,  ECMAScript, PHP, and many other languages, so I think it safe to say it is considerably easier to integrate a different front end into DMS.

Cuda, as I understand it, is a C99 derivative. DMS has a C front end, with explicit support for building various C dialects.  Most of C99 is already built using the dialect mechanism.  That might be a pretty good starting point.

You can try other tools such as ANTLR as an alternative, but I think it will soon become obvious that ANTLR, and Rose and DMS are in very different leagues in terms of their ability to parse, analyze and transform complex systems of real code.